# Select a Salt top file when using saltenv with a gitfs backend

Tags: saltstack

**Background**

I have a Salt instance configured with a *gitfs* backend. By default, this specifies the *master* branch to be the `base` environment. So, when I execute:

```
salt <minion-id> state.apply
```

the *top.sls* file is executed by default.

**Situation**

I'd like to know if there is a way to specify/execute this *top.sls* file while also specifying a `saltenv` (to select a branch):

```
salt <minion-id> state.apply saltenv=<branch>
```

Currently, this returns:

```
minion-id:
-----------
ID: states
Function: no.None
Result: False
Comment: No Top file or external nodes data matches found.
Changes:
```

I know that I can define multiple environments in the *top.sls* file, but the value being passed into `saltenv` is somewhat dynamic. It will always contain a value of `feature/`, but that's the only constant part. I tried adding a wildcarded environment to the *top.sls file*, but that caused compilation errors. I know I can have a two-step process where feature branches get merged to a development branch which is in turn merged to master, but I'd love to avoid creating a development branch just to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish a dynamic link between environments/branches available to Salt's GitFS and the top file using Jinja.

In your `top.sls` file, you can have a top level entry:

```
{{ saltenv }}:
  '*':
    - foo.bar
   ...
```

`{{ saltenv }}` will be replaced with whatever the current environment context is. Usually I define this at runtime, via:

```
some-minion $ sudo salt-call saltutil.sync_modules saltenv=blah
some-minion $ sudo salt-call state.apply saltenv=blah
```

Comment: I must have missed the notification on this one. I'll try this out today or early next week. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm getting error 'no matching salt environments' for such setup